# Import all classes without specifying each one of them in python

Tags: python, class, oop

i'm new to python and just created a few classes in a file called sample.py

```
class Student:
      Name = ''
      Age = ''
      Gender = ''

class Employee:
      EmpName = ''
      EmpAge = ''
      EmpClass = ''
```

Now i created another file called Hello.py and in that imported the above file classes

```
from sample import Student,Employee
```

My question is suppose i have a number of classes in the file sample.py is there any way to import all Classes in sample.py without specifying each one of them.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use this line:

```
from sample import *
```

But do note that it is bad practice to do so as you can easily have a function with the same name in both files which would lead to some ugly side-effects.

I'd recommend that you respect namespace conventions use this instead:

```
import sample

student1 = sample.Student()
```

It may seem like an overkill at first, but I promise you it will save you frustrating hours otherwise spent debugging in the long run.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, but it is *not recommended!* According to [PEP8](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#imports):

> Wildcard imports (from  import *) should be avoided, as they make it unclear which names are present in the namespace, confusing both readers and many automated tools.

The gist is, using wildcard imports makes your code much harder to debug, especially after a couple months when you no longer remember writing the import statement and you're trying to figure out what your code does and where all these classes come from. But if you absolutely must, the syntax is:

```
# Please don't use wildcard imports!
from sample import *
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use though it is not recommend because it will cause namespace pollution. The better way is to `package.property`. For what you want, you can use:

```
from sample import *
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the `__all__` tag in the module and cherry pick what elements to export:

```
class A:
    pass

// will not be exported
class B:
    pass

class C:
    pass


__all__ = [ 'A', 'C' ]
```